# Initiate input file click with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-io

I'm trying to initiate click event while creating wysiwyg pop-up pane.
Code:

```
addPane: function () {

    this.im = this.ne.selectedInstance.selElm().parentTag("IMG");
    var A = new bkElement("div").setStyle({
        padding: "10px"
    }).addClass("uploading_panel").appendTo(this.pane.pane);    

    this.fileInput = new bkElement("input").setAttributes({
        type: "file",
        name: "filename",
        id: "file_upload_wys",
    }).addClass("browse_button").appendTo(A);

    $("#file_upload_wys").focus();

    if ($("#file_upload_wys").is(":focus")) {
        console.log("it is focused");
        $("#file_upload_wys").trigger('click');     
    }
    console.log($("#file_upload_wys"));
},
```

Console shows me:
1: "It is focused"
2: Object[input#file_upload_wys.nicEdit-browse_button property value = "" attribute value = "null"]

But, browse button is not triggered.
To me that's totally not security measures of some browsers, i created similar html code outside and it works.

Comment: What kind of file upload are you using?

Comment: I'm using asynchronous upload script NicUpload. It is an extension for Nicedit wysiwyg. [link](http://nicedit.com/demos.php) @Tomanow